# Why does my script keep redeclaring php function?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script that should basically fetch fields from my MySQL tables which include longitude and latitude and the calculate the driving distance which is then echoed to the user as a list.

For some reason the script only prints the first result from the and then throws an error `Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare GetDrivingDistance()`

```
mysqli_close($conn);            
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "buses";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM matatus 
                    JOIN registered_matatus
                    ON matatus.user_id=registered_matatus.user_id 
                    ORDER BY matatus.vehicle_id 
                    ASC LIMIT 4";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     echo "CON Select a matatu\n";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//Start of  calculate distance and time
$lat1 = "-1.283180";
$long1 = "36.822462";
$lat2 = $row["lat"];
$long2 = $row["lng"];

function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
    $dist = GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2);
    $distance = $dist['distance'];
    $time = $dist['time'];
//End of calculate distance and time
         echo "". $row["id"]. " ". $row["reg_number"]. " (" . $row["sacco"] . ") -$time\n";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Any heads up on how to go around this could be highly appreciated.

Comment: try moving the function out of the loop...

Comment: You are defining a function inside a loop, meaning it doesn't get hoisted like it normally would and you end up trying to redeclare it each time the loop goes through.

Comment: The above code will fail sooner: the SQL is never executed and `$result` is not initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :
You cannot declare function in loop

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM matatus 
                    JOIN registered_matatus
                    ON matatus.user_id=registered_matatus.user_id 
                    ORDER BY matatus.vehicle_id 
                    ASC LIMIT 4";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     echo "CON Select a matatu\n";

function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//Start of  calculate distance and time
$lat1 = "-1.283180";
$long1 = "36.822462";
$lat2 = $row["lat"];
$long2 = $row["lng"];
$dist = GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2);
$distance = $dist['distance'];
$time = $dist['time'];
//End of calculate distance and time
         echo "". $row["id"]. " ". $row["reg_number"]. " (" . $row["sacco"] . ") -$time\n";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GetDrivingDistance function is inside the loop. You can not declare the function with same name again and again in php. It will lead you to the same exact error you are getting.

Try this

```
mysqli_close($conn);            
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "buses";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
  $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM matatus 
                JOIN registered_matatus
                ON matatus.user_id=registered_matatus.user_id 
                ORDER BY matatus.vehicle_id 
                ASC LIMIT 4";
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 echo "CON Select a matatu\n";
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 //Start of  calculate distance and time
 $lat1 = "-1.283180";
$long1 = "36.822462";
$lat2 = $row["lat"];
$long2 = $row["lng"];


$dist = GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2);
$distance = $dist['distance'];
$time = $dist['time'];
//End of calculate distance and time
     echo "". $row["id"]. " ". $row["reg_number"]. " (" . $row["sacco"] . ")         -$time\n";
 }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}


function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
{
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response, true);
$dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
$time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
 }
 $conn->close();
```